# Mapping a column with comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in table A that takes the following values.

> "1,2,3",  "1,2",  "2,1",  "3,2"

I have another table B that has the following records.

> ("1","one"),("2","two"),("1","three")

I would like to get the following.

> "one,two,three", "one,two", "two,one", "three,two"

How do I do this in MySQL?

I have tried the following.

```
select 
    A.comma_separated_numbers,
    group_concat(distinct B.word separator ',') as comma_separated_words
from A inner B 
on find_in_set(B.number, A.comma_separated_numbers)>0 
;
```

Comment: you should change that structure, by making another table where 1,2,3 values from the first table are stored in separate rows. this way it can be easily mapped using standard JOINs. this is how relational tables work

Comment: Thats table B we already have that.

Comment: Please don't close the question the other question is irrelevant.

Comment: The question is how to get "one,two,three", "one,two", "two,one", "three,two"
from A and B. B being the table you are asking me to create.

Comment: Negative. Table B is NOT that. You need a third table, C, where such numbers are stored in rows, not columns

Comment: Then you could use joins to get the mapping. Please read the linked answer, it explains these matters better

Comment: B has numbers stored in diffrent rows. Each entry enclosed in parenthesis is a row.

Comment: I think an answer with a query instead words would benefit us all.

Comment: Comma separated numbers from table A must be stored in table C, each on its row, linked to table A. this is how relational databases work

Comment: This C you are talking about is as useful as A and therefore meaningless to create.
(It only has information thats already in A. Linking to A increase no information.)

Comment: @YourCommonSense
just for the record I was able to do it with the following query
I did not read the other quesion (excessive information is just as bad as insufficient information)

```
select a.col1, group_concat(distinct b.col2 separator ',') from batch_dev.A as a
left join batch_dev.B as b
on find_in_set(b.col1, a.col1)
group by a.col1;
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense The above solution does not use the extra table C you are talking about.